# Codeception: Check if element has focus?

Tags: selenium, codeception

Is there a way to assert that an element (e.g. input or link) has the keyboard focus? I'm using Codeception with Selenium. Couldn't find anything on http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver

Comment: This is actually an interesting question, maybe you can do something with $I->grabAttributeFrom('#element', ':focus'), which should fail if the attribute is not found.

Comment: Good idea, but `:focus` is no HTML attribute, it's a CSS pseudo-class.

Comment: Yes it is, but it was worth a try :). My next try would be to try to target the element using :focus as part of the css or xpath selector inside $I->seeElement(). Next, fiddle around with jQuery's is() function inside $I->executeJS(), and as a last resort try to somehow use Selenium's activeElement() inside $I->executeInSelenium().

Comment: `$I->executeJS('return $("#element").is(":focus")');` worked! :-) Please post it as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Great to hear it worked for you! Answer posted below, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reliable source told me this works:

```
$I->executeJS('return $("#element").is(":focus")');
```

Happy testing!

Comment: Calling a library present in the page is a bad practice in user acceptance tests. It defeats the purpose of the test which should be to reproduce as close a possible the behavior of a user. By calling the code of the page you are disregarding some steps which will expose the test to false positives and extra maintenance. Having a test working doesn't mean that you are validating the feature.

Comment: Please, feel free to post your answer to that similar question here too, others might miss it.

Answer (score 2):

Some more details to the [answer by @sunomad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44165078/1668200)

Activate Codeception's [Asserts Module](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Asserts) in your `acceptance.suite.yml`:

```
modules:
    enabled:
        # ...
        - Asserts
```

Then use this in an Acceptance test:

```
$focus = $I->executeJS('return $("#element").is(":focus")');
$I->assertEquals(true, $focus);
```

Works (through Selenium) with Firefox and Chrome. However, it does not work with PhantomJS - see this issue: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10427

Comment: You know, I had a feeling you might had to use asserts with this. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

To complete the @sunomad's answer. 
If you use the code line :

```
$I->executeJS('return $("#element").is(":focus")');
```

You got this error :

> [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException] unknown error: $ is not a function

Switch `$` by `jQuery`

$I->executeJS('return jQuery("#element").is(":focus")');

And it works !