# Testing text cursor position using Codeception and WebDriver

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver, bdd, codeception

Using Codeception and Gherkin, I'm trying to figure out how to test the automatic updating of text cursor position:

```
When I click "New post"
Then the blinking text cursor should be in the "Title" field
```

The code is something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="js-move-text-cursor-to-post-title-input">
  New post
</a>

…

<label>
  Title
  <input type="text" name="title">
</label>

…

<!-- Some JavaScript to set the text cursor to the "Title" input field -->
```

So, my question is, what can I write in the following step definition to test this feature?

```
/**
 * @Then the blinking text cursor should be in the :label field
 * @param string $label
 */
public function theBlinkingTextCursorShouldBeInTheField(string $label)
{
    // @TODO
}
```

`tests/acceptance.suite.yml`:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Symfony:
            part: SERVICES
        - Doctrine2:
            depends: Symfony
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://localhost:8000
            browser: chrome
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems very similar to another question that was asked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44165078/1668200

Maybe the answers to that question would help you out.

Answer (score 3):

You should test that the pressed keys end up in the expected field rather than checking the cursor:

```
When I click "New post"
When I type "abcd"
Then the "Title" field has the value "abcd"
```

The current API from codeception doesn't seem to provide a method to get the active element or to type in the active field.

So you'll probably have to use the underlying API.

With `$webdriver->switchTo()->activeElement()` :

```
// click "New post"
$I->click('#js-move-text-cursor-to-post-title-input');

// type "abcd" in the focused field
$I->executeInSelenium(function($webdriver) {
  $webdriver->switchTo()->activeElement()->sendKeys('abcd');
});

// assert that the value "abcd" is in the expected field
$I->seeInField('input[name="title"]', 'abcd');
```

, or with `executeJS` :

```
// click "New post"
$I->click('#js-move-text-cursor-to-post-title-input');

// type "abcd" in the focused field
$I->executeJS('return document.activeElement')->sendKeys('abcd');

// assert that the value "abcd" is in the expected field
$I->seeInField('input[name="title"]', 'abcd');
```

, or with the underlying keyboard interface :

```
// click "New post"
$I->click('#js-move-text-cursor-to-post-title-input');

// type "abcd" in the focused field
$I->executeInSelenium(function($webdriver) {
  $webdriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys('abcd');
});

// assert that the value "abcd" is in the expected field
$I->seeInField('input[name="title"]', 'abcd');
```